# How to git push to a remote windows machine using ssh

Tags: windows, git, ssh

When I try to push from a local repository to a remote windows machine, using the next command:

```
git push ssh://username@ip_address:/C/Users/username/project.git master
```

After entering credentials I get this error:

> fatal: ''/c/Users/username/project.git'' does not appear to be a git
>   repository
>
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

It seems like `/C/Users/username/project.git` must be replaced by `C:/Users/username/project.git` (without "/" before C) but when I try this variant, I get another error before asking for credentials:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname ip_address:C:: Name or service not
>   known

Comment: First verify you can access the repository with ssh: `ssh username@ip_address ls /C/Users/username/project.git`. Then fix the URL; it should be `ssh://username@ip_address/C/Users/username/project.git`. See the [different syntax of git URLs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a).

Comment: I verified I can access the repository with `ssh` then `dir /C/Users/username/project.git`. But I still get the same error, even with `ssh://username@ip_address/C/Users/username/project.git`

Answer (score 0):

Any ':' in the SSH URL would make SSH interpret it as [SCP syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php)

An actual URI is as commented `ssh://username@ip_address/C/Users/username/project.git`

Make sure you check the case (lower/upercase) of the path used here.
Try also with `/c/...` vs `/C/...`

Comment: I tried both /C/... and /c/... varietries but still get the error

Comment: @BrainabilGH Strange. Does the remote Windows has Cygwin? As in `ssh://username@ip_address/cygdrive/c//Users/username/project.git`

Comment: No, I it hasn't, I will install it, but can you tell me why do I need Cygwin to push remote?

Comment: @BrainabilGH No need to install it. If it was already there, then the path would have been `/cygdrive/...`, which is why I mentioned it. What version of Widows do you have on that remote server?

Comment: The remote server is running with Windows 10

Comment: @BrainabilGH Is it a Windows 10 1903+ which comes with its own OpenSSH already installed?

Comment: @BrainabilGH And when you do it in two steps (`ssh ssh://username@ip_address`, then `cd /C/Users/username/project.git`), what does `git status` return in that remote shell session?

Comment: Vonc it is a Windows 10 which comes with OpenSSH client pre installed but you must install the server functionality.

Comment: After successful `ssh ssh://username@ip_address`, when I run `cd /C/Users/username/project.git` I get `The specified path was not found`. But I can access the repository from `C:/Users/username>` using `cd project.git` so the problem is in `/C/`

Comment: @BrainabilGH Dod you try with `/c/`?